# python empty list output for list comprehension from txt

Tags: python, list-comprehension, readlines, startswith

Trying to read a txt file and filter irrelevant lines.
Some lines are random strings, some being with '#' hashtag character.

```
base_txt = open(path, 'rU')
  txt = base_txt.readlines()
  txt = [x for x in base_txt if x.startswith('#')]
  print txt
  print len(txt)
```

The output is an empty list. If I print txt before the list comprehension then it prints out all the strings in the file.

Is there a syntax error I'm doing?

Comment: Can you paste 5-10 lines of your text file in your question please?

Comment: You're looping over the wrong variable. Should be `txt = [x for x in txt ...]`

Comment: `for x in base_txt` -> `for x in txt`. The second time you're reading the lines, the file pointer is at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is ok, you're just looping over the wrong variable. It should be

```
txt = [x for x in txt if x.startswith('#')]
```

instead of

```
txt = [x for x in base_txt if x.startswith('#')]
```